# 'Your query does not include the specified expression 'X' as part of an aggregate function' How do I fix this (beginner)

Tags: sql, database, syntax-error, max, ms-access-2010

I am new to SQL, doing an assignment whereby information must be selected from two databases based on the highest 'Procurement Rate' for a specific region. I'll be honest, I have no idea what I'm doing and would appreciate any help. I have some code written & it only seems to work when I have ORDER BY written at the end, however, ORDER BY is giving me multiple results, whereas I need a single result. Im sorry if the explanation is poor, I really have little understanding in this area.

```
SELECT

                  SalesPeople.SalesPersonID,
                  FirstName,
                  LastName,
                  Region, 
                  SalesRevenueYear1,
                  SalesRevenueYear2,
                  MAX (ProcurementCost)

FROM
        
                  ProductRevenueAndCosts

INNER JOIN  SalesPeople
  ON                ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesPersonID = SalesPeople.SalesPersonID


WHERE

                  ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesPersonID =5
```

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause here.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried a GROUP BY clause and it gave me the five results associated with the specific region in question, but not solely the highest procurement rate which is the intended result. Is there a way I can remove the other four results?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
    SELECT
      SalesPeople.SalesPersonID,
      FirstName,
      LastName,
      Region, 
      SalesRevenueYear1,
      SalesRevenueYear2,
      MAX (ProcurementCost)
FROM
      ProductRevenueAndCosts
GROUP BY          
      SalesPeople.SalesPersonID,
      FirstName,
      LastName,
      Region, 
      SalesRevenueYear1,
      SalesRevenueYear2;
```

Thank you.